# TinyMCE Full Screen Command Not Working

Tags: javascript, tinymce

According to what I could find on the net, to put tinyMCE editor to full screen mood automatically you need to do this.

```
oninit: function () { 
  tinymce.get('editingArea').execCommand('mceFullScreen');
}
```

However it's not working for me.

Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

JS Fiddle Example : http://jsfiddle.net/g3K5M/1/

Comment: your fiddle works fine for me.

Comment: Dies it goto full screen mode automatically?

Comment: yes it does. chrome..

Comment: I just tried using chrome. It doesn't work. There's an option to goto full screen in the View menu. Please select it and see that's the full screen mode. not the default way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was occuring because I was using the latest version.

TinyMCE 4.

I switched to 3.x and tried this out. It works perfectly.

So I'm going to switch to 3.8 version until 4 is stabilized and these features are readily available there.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with 4.0.16. It took some digging and trying because there don't seem to be any straight answers for the 4.x versions.

```
setup: function(ed) {
            ed.on('init', function() {
                tinymce.editors[0].execCommand('mceFullScreen');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version for v4:

```
tinymce.init({
    init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
        editor.execCommand('mceFullScreen');
    }
});
```

Though, both for the answer above and with this version, the editor doesn't repaint properly and the window has to be resized before it actually fills the screen...